# Retrieving virtual memory size (VSZ) value of a single process

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I would like to get VSZ value of a specific process running on Linux server

The following command:

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }'
```

is fetching all process memory high usage to low.

How can I fetch only (VSZ) value of a single process.

Let's say, I wanted to get the VSZ value of "proxyfarm". How can I achieve this using the command:

```
ps ux | grep httpd | grep proxyfarm    can fetch proxyfarm complete details.But, i need only VSZ of it.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check virtual memory size (vsz) values under `/proc/<PID>/stats`

According to [/proc man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), the column #23 of `/proc/<PID>/stats` represents  vsz values in **bytes**.

For example,
PID is 3917 then:

```
cat /proc/3917/stat | cut -d" " -f23
```

Important to note, that the reported vsz values under `/proc/PID/stats` are estimated in **bytes**, while the output of the command `ps -o vsz= -p "$pid"` is estimated in **kibibyte or kib** (1 KiB is equal to 1024 byte).

In order to convert the output of vsz under `/proc/PID/stat` from **byte** to **kib**:

```
cat /proc/3917/stat | cut -d" " -f23 | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($1/1024))' args
```

Comment: That assumes the process name doesn't contain space or newline characters. Generally, to get data from `stats`, you need to look after the last occurrence of `)` in their (which may not be on the first line). `/proc/pid/status` is easier to parse.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas . Correct! On other side... actually, `/proc man` is referring to `ps man` to get this value and many others..

Comment: I'm getting result for command : cat /proc/34346/stat | cut -d" " -f23. but its not correct value. Can you suggest if i missed anything .

Comment: Hi @sundar. you are correct. because in `/proc/PID/stat` you get the vsz in bytes while the command `ps ` above output memory in kibibyte `kib` so just convert between both and you will find the same numbers, however `1 KiB is equal to 1024 byte`.

Comment: @sundar. Use the command above like this `ps -o vsz= -p 34346`

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly,

```
ps -o vsz= -p "$pid"
```

would print the size of the process of id `$pid` in (virtual) memory in 1024 byte units as a decimal integer.

With the `ps` utility from procps on Linux, if you replace `-p "$pid"` with `-C proxyfarm`, you'll have that information for all the processes that have `proxyfarm` as their name.

The POSIX equivalent, assuming process names don't contain blanks or newlines:

```
ps -Ao vsz= -o comm= | awk '$2 == "proxfarm" {print $1}'
```

You can replace `comm` with `args` to search for processes whose arg list starts with the `proxfarm` word instead of the process name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. unfortunately, I'm not getting neither result nor error when using command : ps -o vsz= -p "$34346". Could you help me.

Comment: @sundar, `$pid` is meant to be a shell variable, as in `pid=34346`. Use `ps -o vsz= -p 34346` if you don't need to use a variable. `$34346` would be either like `${3}4346` (probably expanded to 4346 as `$3` is probably unset) or `${34346}` (probably empty) depending on the shell.

Comment: Thank you so much . I'm getting the correct value now :)